# DataContractException in hosted WCF service

Tags: wcf, serialization, datacontractserializer, datacontract

I am trying a host a service where there is a method that returns the following type:

```
[DataContract]
[Obfuscation(ApplyToMembers = true, Exclude = true)]
[Serializable]
public class Output
{
    [DataMember]
    public DataSet dsOutput{get;set;}
}
```

The method signature is as follows:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet]
function Output matchData(DataSet pDSSide1,DataSet pDSSide2)
{
   return new Output();
}
```

On browsing the service I encounter the following exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: An exception was thrown in a call to a WSDL export extension:System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior
>    contract: http://tempuri.org/:TesterTool ---->
>
> System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException: Type 'System.Data.DataRow' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute.  If the type is a collection, consider marking it with the CollectionDataContractAttribute.  See the Microsoft .NET Framework documentation for other supported types.
>   `

Any suggestions.

Comment: yes, don't return DataSet, how would the framework be able to parse all possible DataSets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a good practice to send a DataTable over a service.

As stated by govindaraj [here](http://forums.asp.net/post/4810553.aspx):

> The best way is to use custom collection of custom object.
>
> If you're using 2.0, then you can use generic collection instead of
>   custom collection to reduce code.
>
> How?
>
> 1. Create a custom data object (containing only private fields and public properties for each field) that is similar to each row in the
>      datatable.
> 2. Create a layer that will do all database (in this case, dataset) access and translation to the custom object.
> 3. All client code will access that layer.

Comment: When copying the words of others, you absolutely must provide attribution like I did above. Please be sure to do this in the future.